# Prove that the following sum is a branch of log(z)

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

**Problem statement:**

> > Let $f(z) :$
> >
> > $$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n-1}\cdot\left(\frac{(z-1)^{n}}{n}\right)} $$

**Q:** How can we prove that the previous mapping is *a branch of logarithm* on $\mathbb{D}(1,1)\;$ (open disk)

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:** If $U \subset \mathbb{C}^{*}$ an open set and $f$ a branch of logarithm prove that :

i)
$ f$ is analytic

ii) $f'(z) = \frac{1}{z} $

Comment: The series is not a representation of the logarithm function.  Did you really want the denominator to be $n!$?

Comment: That's exactly what's written in my lecture , but I don't see how we can prove it , so it's a mistake ?

Comment: If we change the denominator to just $n$ is it working?

Comment: Yes, if the denominator is $n$ instead of $n!$, then the series represents the complex logarithm for $|z-1|<1$

Comment: @MarkViola Could you show me how you prove it ? Is it because $e^{f(z)}=f(z)$

Comment: Do you know how to show that $f$ is analytic on the open unit disk with center at $z=1$?

Comment: No I don't know how